# Is there way a implicit typing exist in Apex?

Tags: apex

Many modern statically-typed languages provide the ability to write variables without explicitly providing the type.

For example, C# uses var:

var foo = new Bar();

var foo2 = "blah blah";

Does this functionality exist in Apex?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Apex is strongly typed language. PFB the line in [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_intro_what_is_apex.htm) -

> Apex is a strongly typed, object-oriented programming language that allows developers to execute flow and transaction control statements on Salesforce servers in conjunction with calls to the API.

You can get detail in this [document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_qs_core_concepts.htm) and basic structure of variable declaration is like -

```java
datatype​ variable_name [ = value];
```

Answer (score 0):

As Ysr Shk said, Apex is strongly typed. However, all built-in and custom datatypes in Apex actually ultimately derive from something called `Object`. The Object class includes a few infrastructural aspects such as equality checking and conversion to string amongst others, with default implementations of these methods, though this isn't covered in the official documentation for some reason.

Declaring a variable with the Object type is a little similar to the use of "var", but not the same:

```
Object foo = new Bar();

Object foo2 = 'blah blah';
```

The difference here, compared with what you find in C# (or other languages supporting implicit typing), is that now you have your `Bar` instance known as an `Object`, the only operations you can perform on it are those that exist in the `Object` class, and you cannot pass this variable to a method that accepts a `Bar` instance parameter without first explicitly casting it to `Bar`.

There are other limitations too when it comes to things like `List<Object>` vs `List<String>` - e.g. it isn't possible to simply cast the list of objects to be a list of strings, but instead you can only iterate the objects and cast each to a string in turn.

Note that even `SObject` extends `Object`.